# How can I set different colors in the same label?

Tags: colors, jframe, label, netbeans-7, foreground

I have to set different messages in a label but I could not change that different messages' color. How can I set different colors in a same label?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure on how to answer your question, but i do have an idea that you might like...
You could just try and make a custom label (using the paintComponent() or the paint() method. I would recommend paintComponent().)

For instance:

---

(If you're going to use paintComponent() you need to put it into a JPanel class,
                  but if you chose to do paint() you can leave it in your JFrame class. If you chose to use the paint() method, you need to get rid of the super.paintComponent(g) line.)

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);

      //first color and first half
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(10, 10, 40, 40);

      //second color and second half
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(50, 10, 40, 40);

      //Obviously sets the text, its color, etc.
      g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawString("TEXT", 25, 36);

}
```

Now, assuming you know how to use all this. You can go ahead and just use this, and make the colors and text what ever you want.

**IF YOU DONT UNDERSTAND SOMETHING, PLEASE FEEL FREE TO ASK!**

**If this helped please thumbs up!**

Comment: Of course, this way of doing things will take allot more effort and time. To get the "custom label" how you want it to look.